# Call on php Script onclick using Jquery and Refresh the Data without Reloading the Page?

Tags: php, jquery

Here's what's up: I have php parsers that save data to some local files that are fetched once the page is loaded via includes. I want to give a user an opportunity to refresh that data, so for that I need the parser to start up again and pass new data string to the page's element without reloading the page.

Can someone, please, help me, my brain is melting already. Probably I just need a plain simple AJAX call, but please don't spare the proper syntax.

Here's how I see it (might be very wrong):

```
<element id="button"></element>

<div id="new_data"></div>

<jquery>
$('#button').onclick(function() {

call for test.php, let it do it's job and get the $result_string

$('#new_data').innerHTML($result_string);

});
</jquery>


<?test.php

function parser() {

all in place;

return $result_string;
}
?>
```

P.S. Also there's something to do with forms, but cannot figure it out either.

SOLVED!!!

And here's what worked for me, if someone should sumble upon this question:

```
    $("#button").bind('click', function() {
$.post("test.php", function(data) {
$("#data").html(data);
});
});
```

or

```
$("#button").bind('click', function() {
$('#data').load('test.php');
});
```

and in test.php just a simple `echo $result;` in the end, works perfect and quite fast.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need a ajax call on button click which will get the result_string, try this:

```
$('#button').onclick(function() {
    //using simple ajax post..

    $.post('test.php',function(data){
        $('#new_data').html(data); //here i am returning the data as HTML from test.php..
   });
});
```

If you need the return_string as javascript objects then you can send JSON as response:

```
function parser() {

    all in place;

    return echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result_string));
}
```

and get it as object in post

```
$.post('test.php',function(data){
    $('#new_data').html(data.result); 
});
```

though bit confused about your question i think this will get you started..

Comment: also didn't get it, return echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result_string)); highlights syntax error!

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for ajax Request.

```
   $('#button').onclick(function() {
      jQuery.ajax({ 
        type:'post',
        url:'test.php',
        data:[],
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(rs)
        {
          $('#new_data').innerHTML(rs.result_string);
         }
        failure : function(rs)
        {
            alert(rs.errorMesage);
        }
     });
  });
```

Comment: nothing worked, shows up syntax error on 11th line! what should i put into test.php, just simple return $value;?